# scp and rsync do not work (ssh works)

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

In my Debian Squeeze server, `scp` and `rsync` do not seem to copy over anything. Works fine with another server though (so not a client problem). When using scp, it just creates an empty file and waits. `/etc/bash.bashrc` contains `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` at the top as well. SSH works fine. What might be the problem?

## Diagnostics

`foo.bar`: plain text file of size 10899 bytes

### `scp -vvv  /tmp/foo.bar server:/tmp`

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host server, user (unspecified), command scp -v -t -- /tmp
OpenSSH_5.8p1-hpn13v10, OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for server
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server.com [111.222.111.222] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Remote is NON-HPN aware
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1-hpn13v10
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "server.com" from file "/home/alanhaggai/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: AUTH STATE IS 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-ctr'
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-ctr'
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 138/256
debug2: bits set: 514/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA a1:28:fd:35:98:19:ee:73:19:a8:de:1d:20:33:b6:6d
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "server.com" from file "/home/alanhaggai/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "111.222.111.222" from file "/home/alanhaggai/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'server.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 525/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_rsa (0x6813f0)
debug2: key: /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/alanhaggai/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp db:e7:33:bd:a8:1e:ae:fa:3b:3d:85:da:c0:9f:4a:6d
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA db:e7:33:bd:a8:1e:ae:fa:3b:3d:85:da:c0:9f:4a:6d
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to server.com ([111.222.111.222]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: HPN to Non-HPN Connection
debug1: Final hpn_buffer_size = 2097152
debug1: HPN Disabled: 0, HPN Buffer Size: 2097152
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Enabled Dynamic Window Scaling

debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t -- /tmp
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
Sending file modes: C0644 10899 foo.bar
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 30
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
Sink: C0644 10899 foo.bar
debug2: channel 0: written 30 to efd 6
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
foo.bar                                                                                                                 100%   11KB  10.6KB/s  10.6KB/s   00:00    
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 3
```

After a while:

### `^C` (on interrupt)

```
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 2.
```

### `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

**Inference**: Not a client-side problem as `scp` and `rsync` work fine with another server

### Steps Taken

- OpenSSH server was removed, purged and re-installed
- Adjusted permissions of `.ssh/` and files within

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have been a **once in a blue moon** bug with the ISP. Happy that it has not occurred ever since. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the misbehaving server has some unusual stuff in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` or other startup scripts. Every time I've seen similar behaviour there has been some autorunning software on .bashrc or something similar.

Comment: I have removed both the files, but the behaviour exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though useful, my case seems to be a different problem. I am suspecting the ISP (that the client uses) is playing bad. When I tried from a different connection, `scp` worked!